# Using LENGTH(computed column) in ORDER BY in Postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, column-alias

```sql
SELECT  concat(first_name,last_name)  AS full_name from customer
ORDER BY  length(full_name);
```

I tried to run this in postgre sql database.
I give me this erro

```
[42703] ERROR: column "full_name" does not exist
```

How would I resolve this?  Order rows by length of full name.

Comment: `order by length(concat(firstname, lastname))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres adheres to the standard by allowing column aliases as `order by` keys.  So this works:

```
SELECT  CONCAT(first_name, last_name)  AS full_name
FROM customer
ORDER BY full_name;
```

However, it does not extend this to *expressions* using the aliases.  You can fix this using subqueries or CTEs.  I might also suggest a lateral join:

```
SELECT v.full_name
FROM customer c CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (VALUES (CONCAT(c.first_name, c.last_name))) v(full_name)
ORDER BY v.full_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try either of the below?

```
SELECT  concat(first_name,last_name) COLLATE "C"  AS full_name from customer
ORDER BY  length(full_name)
```

OR

```
SELECT  concat(first_name,last_name)  from customer
ORDER BY  length(concat(first_name,last_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work, and avoids the double use of `concat()`

```
WITH results AS (
  SELECT concat(first_name, last_name) AS full_name FROM customer
)
SELECT full_name FROM results ORDER BY length(full_name)
```